# Amplify CI/CD for back-end continuous integration

Tags: aws-amplify, cicd, aws-amplify-cli

The Amplify CLI does not allow updates to change authorized features, I wonder if there is a simpler and more organized way to perform CI/CD for the back-end. i.e. simply adding and updating new storage to the API

(Amplify CLI update API only gives options on lambda but not accessibilities settings to change on other features like auth/storage/function)